# MVC design issue with notification from view to controller

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller

mine is not really a programming problem but a design problem regarding the Model-View-Controller design pattern in IOS programming. I am new to IOS but I really want to do the things in the right way. So I have this view that does some animations but I want to "notify" the Controller when the animations end. I know that the View cannot have a reference to the Controller. Reading the page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/StreamlineYourAppswithDesignPatterns/StreamlineYourApps/StreamlineYourApps.html

In the first figure the view - controller communication is only **user action** (IBActions from the view) and **update** from controller. Possible solution that I have thought:

- Notification, even it does not exist in the figure it could be OK
- Controller polls the status of a property of the view until the animations finishes (might block the main thread if I'm not wrong)
- Key Value Observing, seems to be like a Notification.

Do you have any idea or best practice to exchange? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could use NSNotifications, they're better used when you want to notify multiple objects, or you don't know what object you want to notify. It could also be used if there's no easy way to get a reference to the view from the controller, but that's not usually the case.
So, the one way you left out, delegation, is probably the best approach. The view would define a delegate protocol, and call a delegate method when its animations end. The controller, which would set itself as the delegate of the view, would implement that delegate method to respond appropriately to the end of those animations.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about delegation, seems it is a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code I'll assume that the ViewController is the object that caused the animation. If so, then the ending of the animation should be handled inside a block. Example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^(void) { your animation code here }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) { your completion code here }];
```

Comment: No, the view is the one which start the animations. I cannot do it in controller because the view has the references to the subviews also to do it in a neat way I don't want to do it in the View Controller. Thanks

Comment: Then I think notifications is your best solution.